# Reference: Continuity of Eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, perturbation-theory

I am looking for an appropriate reference for the following fact.

> For each $X \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}_{\text{sym}}$ (symmetric matrix),
>   there exist $\varepsilon, L > 0$, such that
>   for all $H \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}_{\text{sym}}$ with $\|H\| \le \varepsilon$
>   the following holds:
>
> There are orthogonal matrices $P, Q$, such that
>   \begin{equation*}
>  Q^\top \, X \, Q = \Lambda(X)
> \end{equation*}
>   and
>   \begin{equation*}
>  P^\top \, (X + H) \, P = \Lambda(X + H)
> \end{equation*}
>   and
>   \begin{equation*}
>  \| P - Q \| \le L \, \| H \|.
> \end{equation*}

Here, $\lambda(X)$ is the diagonal matrix containing the eigenvalues of $X$.
That is, $P$ and $Q$ are bases of eigenvectors of $X$ and $X + H$, respectively.
Here, it is crucial that we can choose $Q$ in dependence of $H$.

This result can be found in 
[this article](http://dx.doi.org/10.1137/S0036142901393814), see Lemma 4.3.
I feel, however, that a reference from 2003 is not appropriate for this "simple" fact.

Comment: Crosspost on mathoverflow: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/196433/reference-continuity-of-eigenvectors

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The "standard" reference for all results of such types is

**Kato, T.**,  *Perturbation theory for linear operators*. Springer-Verlag, 1976

The finite dimensional theory is well exposed in Chapter 2, with the non-analytic dependence in section 5.

---

As a side remark: your statement is actually **not**, as your title suggests, about "continuity of eigenvectors", which is false (see Chapter 2, section 5.3 of the above citation). What you are describing is the continuity of eigenprojections.

---

If you want to be historical, these types of problems were originally treated by Rellich in the 1930s. A more detailed account was provided in his 1954 lecture notes [which are freely available](https://archive.org/details/perturbationtheo00rell).