# What is an eigenprojection?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

I have seen this question, https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1146455, but don't understand the answer because I can't find a definition of an eigenprojection I understand.  It seems to be an operator mapping to an eigenspace...  Can it simply be a matrix whose columns are the eigenvectors corersponding to a single eigenvalue?

Comment: Generally speaking a *projection* is a mapping $T:V\to V$ such that $T(T(v)) = T(v)$.  So *eigenprojection* should probably be understood as a linear transformation that projects onto an eigenspace.  However in more specialized settings, where the eigenspace corresponds to a symmetric or self-adjoint transformation on an inner product space, we would likely want an *orthogonal projection* (since eigenspaces for distinct eigenvalues will be orthogonal).

Comment: In your context, the "eigenprojection associated with $\lambda$" is the orthogonal projection onto the eigen*space* associated with $\lambda$.  If $A$ is a matrix whose columns are a maximal collection of linearly independent eigenvectors, then the eigenprojection is given by $A(A^TA)^{-1}A^T$.

Comment: What do you mean by a "maximal collection"?  In what sense is it maximal?  Also, what is your point in presenting this expression, $A(A^TA)^{-1}A^T=I$?