# Prove the existence of a sequence of eigenvectors

Tags: matrices, convergence-divergence, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, normed-spaces

Let $(A_n),(B_n)$ be two sequences of $n\times n$ (growing sizes) symmetric real matrices. Suppose that their difference $\Delta_n:=A_n-B_n$ statisfies

$$||\Delta_n||\to 0 \text{ as } n\to \infty,$$

where $||\cdot||$ denotes the Frobenius norm. Let $(U_n)$ be a sequence of $n\times k$ matrices ($k$ fixed) satisfying

$$A_n=U_nV_nU'_n \hspace{1cm} U'_nU_n=I_k \hspace{1cm} \text{for each } n$$

where $V_n$ is the $k\times k$ diagonal matrix containing the $k$ largest eigenvalues of $A_n$ in decreasing order. In other words, $U_n$ is a matrix of normalized eigenvectors for $A_n$, for each $n$.

**Question.** Does there exist a corresponding sequence $(Q_n)$ of $n\times k$ matrices of normalized eigenvectors for $(B_n)$ such that

$$||U_n-Q_n|| \to 0 \text{ as } n\to \infty \hspace{0.5cm}? $$

I want to apply the result stated in this post [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1133071/522332). Is it possible?

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: I am not sure. The eigenprojectors are continuous, but you would need an uniform continuity, uniformly for different $n$

Comment: @Exodd I see. And what if the sequences $(A_n),(B_n)$ are nested? In other words the upper left part of $A_{n+1}$ is $A_n$ for each $n$. Same for $(B_n)$.

Comment: Also you have problems when you have eigenvalues with multiplicities, since the diagonalization is not unique

Comment: @Exodd Right, but can I show it assuming distinct eigenvalues for each $n$?

Comment: I think you can still build counterexamples where the eigenvalues tend to be equal as $n$ goes to infinity